# How to disable popup when is clicked on the leaflet map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, wms

This is mu problem, when is clicked on the map it tries to open an pop-up ot something like this and downloads me a file everytime is clicked on the map, how to prevent this...

Code of the layer component:

```
import { useLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import * as WMS from "leaflet.wms";

function CustomWMSLayer(props) {
  const { url, options, layers } = props;
  const ctx = useLeaflet();
  const map = ctx.map;

  // Add WMS source/layers
  const source = WMS.source(url, options);

  for (let name of layers) {
    source.getLayer(name).addTo(map);
  }

  return null;
}

export default CustomWMSLayer;
```

This is how i invoke it in the map:

```
  <CustomWMSLayer
              layers={["Sentinel-2"]}
              options={{
                format: "image/vnd.jpeg-png",
                transparent: "true",
                tiled: "true",
                crossOrigin: null,
              }}
              url="https://kade.si/cgi-bin/mapserv?"
            />
```

I saw this in the console:
[image]

But i don't want to make request when is clicked..

Comment: The answer on how to disable `getFeatureInfo` requests is in the documentation: https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms#identify-getfeatureinfo

Answer (score 0):

There is a special import in leaflet library called Popup:

Example:

```
 import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
```

You can add it or not. If you import it you use it inside of Marker import:

```
<Marker position={position} icon={myIcon}>
          <Popup>This is the address</Popup>
</Marker>
```

Comment: yeah but i want to avoid this

Comment: https://github.com/SoilViews/SoilViews/blob/master/src/components/dashboard/Dashboard.js --> this is my code where i initialize tha map and added the custom layer

Answer (score 0):

`identify` will disable the popup, `info_format` will define the output format.

Add these to options:

```
    options={{
        format: "image/vnd.jpeg-png",
        transparent: "true",
        tiled: "true",
        crossOrigin: null,
        identify: false,
        info_format: 'application/json',
    }}
```